# Feature to resize images?

Tags: feature-request, images

I found the screenshots I upload to my questions and answers very big. I know this is because I am using a retina display. The resolution is higher and stuff.

For instance, in my [latest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36952273/5133585), I took a few screenshots and added them to the answer. They were so large that I need to scroll for a long time to get to the bottom and read the rest of the post.

I know that I can use CSS to resize the image, but it's hard to keep the aspect ratio and the image will look bad.

So maybe add a feature that automatically resizes the images which are larger than 300px in height to 300px in height and keep the aspect ratio? This way people can scroll less.

Comment: Even on a normal computer, this is an issue with some images. I don't feel like every image is so important it needs to take up half the screen.